# Can I configure JGroups with both a TCP and UDP section at the same time

Tags: tcp, udp, jgroups, jboss-cache

We have been running a JBOSS Cache cluster for a few years now in UDP and for the most part it's been fine.

We had to add a node outside the firewall so we reconfigured it for TCP and have since had a lot of problems.

Can we have both TCP/unicast and UDP/multicast sections in the same config file so that we are using the TCP for the one node on the other side of the firewall and UDP for everything else?

(I'm guessing this can't be done since there is only the "Config" level and everything under it is in the same stack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. If you had just 1 node outside a firewall, you could use STOMP (see the JGroups manual) to talk to the other nodes, but this requires everything to be a string.
Or you could use TUNNEL:PING and a GossipRouter, but that's not really fast as everything's routed through that GR.
As an alternative, you could look into RELAY2.